# Advices about the navigation bar at the top of the page?

Tags: navigation

- I haven't figured out what icon is suitable for the `signup` button?

[image]

- Also there's a filter dropdown down there to filter articles, not
  sure where to put it, or if this place is fine

[image]

- I didn't upload any articles yet, but the search bar will appear
  after you press the button in the right side;

[image]

- I used radix-ui color and this is the light theme;

[image]

Any advices regarding the theme is welcome...

Comment: A note to the light theme. Try and use the developer tools in your browser, or something like stark https://www.getstark.co/ to check your contrasts. And provide better accessibility. The yellow and the light/dark turkise are probably not strong enough in contrast.

Answer (score 1):

those are a lot of questions. I guess the major of those questions can be answered with page hierarchy. I would recommend you, to read this article, especially the third subchapter might help you here.
[1]: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/visual-hierarchy-ux-definition/

As a short summary I would look into the topic Gestalt principles and especially the first one. Principle of closure. That means that the user perceives specific elements as a group or one element. In UX design you can use this principle to help the user scan pages quickly and find whatever they search for.
In your case you should group LogIn and anything connected to the profile at one point and the search as well as the filter should be visually grouped. Visually grouping means putting everything that belongs to one group, closer together and leaving space between the groups. On top of that you can also let elements that are on the same hierarchy, look the same. The eye of the user should be drawn to the most important action on the page. In your example the moon seems (visually) to be the most important action on the page.

The placement of your searchline can be answered by what exactly you are filtering or searching through. If the searchline is not meant to search through the entire system, you should put it below the header and add a headline above it, that helps the user to know what informations they can filter or search through.

Your design would definitely benefit from smart group and distance choices. Questions like a fitting Icon and modes are secondary and might get solved by fixing the hierarchy.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have been told to group all buttons and one side (left) and search bar at one side, because some blogging websites do it, now i am not sure how to actually find the truth about the best UI/UX choice

Comment: It totally depends on the function of buttons and the total count, whether to group all buttons on the same side or not. Try to group buttons that are related in functions at one place. Place the buttons where the user needs them and would probably search for them.

Answer (score 0):

cool project!

It might be worth it to split your questions up into different threads if you require detailed answers, but I will try to answer them here as best as possible.

### General Advice

A lot of your questions can be generally answered with: *Steal!*

Unless your goal is to create a super innovative navigation bar, it is rarely a bad idea to see what competitors or sites that your users will probably know already are doing to solve a problem and then doing it the same way unless you see something seriously wrong about it. To apply this advice:

### Icon for signup

**There is probably no fitting one**. Why? Because literally no site is using one. Not Facebook, not the New York Times, not my local gym. The closest you are going to find is stuff like YouTube where there is a button saying `Sign In`  with a little icon accompanying the text.

This doesn't mean that it is impossible to design one, but there is no standard that is understood by users right now.

Signing in is also probably a really important action (as in: the thing you want me to do most on your site, or close) so making it really clear is really the move here.

### Filter dropdown position

This element is not really part of the nav bar, is it? So it is more important to position it in relation to the articles, once they exist. I think top left or top right above the article list is probably just fine. Feel free to check reddit or another article accumulator that your users are likely to know to steal a design solution.

### Search bar functionality

Having the search bar appear on click feels fancy but may be frustrating - users have to do an extra click for basically no reason. Trying to find that one hilarious article whose headline you kind of remember is frustrating enough already, don't make it harder.

### Color theme

Using a predefined color theme is a good idea, however I think you should be careful with the blue/cyan background. It's *really* aggressive. It is really easy to get baited into making websites way to colorful, especially when designing with a color palette. [This great article](https://www.refactoringui.com/previews/building-your-color-palette) outlines this well. That said, strong color can be good branding, check [HackerNoon](https://hackernoon.com/). Just be conscious about this.

### TLDR: Your outlined problems are mostly common stuff that users expect to work in the usual way. Find 1-3 relevant websites and steal the parts of their designs you think work best.

Comment: interesting, thank you, cyan seems a cool color, but I might look at other themes options, it seem like i need to follow some set of standards to apply a proper UI and UX